# Overloading method for single instance as well as IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have created two overloads of a method for `IEnumerable<T>` as well as a single instance:

```
void DoSomething<T>(T arg)
   where T:class
{ // do something }
void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
   where T:class
{ // do something }
```

The problem is that arrays and lists are not recognized as `IEnumerable<T>` and that for cases such as

```
DoSomething(new MyObject[]{o1,o2,o3})
```

the overload of the single instance is called with `T` being `MyObject[]`.

Does anyone have a nice design that would always bring me to the overload with `IEnumerable<T>` also for any other container implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, such as arrays and lists?

Comment: Why you have a class constraint on `int`? Remove that on the `IEnumerable` overload and cast the array to `(IEnumerable<int>)`

Comment: Sorry, edited the example. This just came from simplifying my code...

Comment: You cannot do it using overloaded methods.  `int[]` is a class, and this is no worse match than being `IEnumerable<int>`, and the compiler resolves it to the first match it finds.  C# doesn't support negative constraints (f.e., where T : ! IEnumerable<T>).  Your only option is to distinguish at runtime in your code.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I have come to the same conclusion and have already implemented this. I was, however, hoping for something nicer...

Comment: @Nick It doesn't use "the first match it finds".  There is no order to the overloads.  There are a detailed set of rules for which overload is "better" when two overloads are applicable for a given call site.  The non-IEnumerable overload is better in this case.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this. Basically add casting before you call method.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xwqp5n

Comment: So you leave responsibility to the user of the API to know that your API is implemented incorrectly and to fix the bug?